# Create a Round Gradient Progress Bar in iOS with CoreGraphics

Tags: ios, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I want to make something like this:

[image: Circle progress bar gradient]

I tried to make it with core Graphics like this:

```
    float radius = CGRectGetWidth(rect)/2.0f - self.circleBorderWidth/2.0f;
float angleOffset = 0;

UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect))
                                                     radius:radius
                                                 startAngle:-angleOffset
                                                   endAngle:(mCircleSegs + 1)/(float)kCircleSegs*M_PI*2 - angleOffset
                                                  clockwise:YES];

CGPathRef shape = CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath(aPath.CGPath, NULL, 3, kCGLineCapSquare, kCGLineJoinMiter, 1.0f);

CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextAddPath(ctx, shape);
CGContextClip(ctx);

AngleGradientLayer *angle = [[AngleGradientLayer alloc] init];
angle.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1].CGColor,
                (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1].CGColor,
                nil];


CGContextClipToRect(ctx, self.bounds);
[angle drawInContext:ctx];

[angle release];
```

But I think I am on the wrong track here. It doesn't look like the example. Is CoreGraphics able to draw something like this? how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bezier path you use as a clip seems to be just a fraction of a circle, while in the image you show, the path is more complex : 2 fractions of a circle, linked by 2 lines, the whole path having a 'ring' shape.

This approach should work, I used it for a timer with the same kind of look.
Although I didn't used directly [AngleGradientLayer](https://github.com/paiv/AngleGradientLayer), I modified its `- (CGImageRef)newImageGradientInRect:(CGRect)rect` method to return a UIImage.
But I had to rotate this image by + PI/2, as Pavlov gradient angular gradient starts horizontally.

I use a UIImage, because it's a background that DOESN'T change, so I saved an instance of this UIImage in my layer, and draw it whenever I update the clipping path

```
- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{

    UIBezierPath *currentPath = [self timerPath];
   // other drawing code for glow (shadow) and white stroke)
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, currentPath.CGPath);
    // clip !
    CGContextClip(ctx);
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, self.bounds, _circularGradientImage.CGImage);

    //_circularGradientImage from modified newImageGradientInRect method.

}
```

Here's what I get :

[image]

Comment: The problem is not the 2 fractions of the circle.  The problem is the drawing of the gradient.  I really have no idea how you can draw something like this with core graphics.

Comment: Yes! but as you see in the picture above, when the progress bar is 20%, 60%, 80%,... the end of the first fraction is always the whitest.  So a background layer is not the solution.  In fact I guess we need a background that is adapting with the progress itself...

Comment: Gradient also need to be transparent. And in your solution I see a very small white border.  I also got such a white border.  I am not sure how to remove this anyway.

Comment: The white border in my example was intentional :)

Comment: You should avoid re-drawing what can be done with a single transformation : in your case, if the 'full white' is always at the beginning, use the same gradient image, applying a rotation so that it fits the current progress...

Comment: @Hans could you post your solution in your post please for future reference? Thank you